# Do you lose any performance by using your own cdn instead of a common one?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently trying to structure my project to get the fastest load times. I'm at a point now where I can put my CSS and JS on my own CloudFront CDN or I can use the maxcdn links for bootstrap, jquery, etc.

My initial thoughts would be that using maxcdn would be better because it would probably already be cached from other sites but, isn't that the reason for my own cdn.

Any feedback on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I beg to differ. The loading of resources and their performance impact is a big part of the development process.

Comment: You are effectively asking what is the best way for you to architect your application without providing details of your project or metrics on load times. I don't think the site can provide you with an answer without resorting to guesses and opinions. You should take it to another site until you have programming problems to solve. Or, take it to the Stack Overflow chat rooms.

Comment: @jww I'm asking a simple question on the effect/impact of using cloudfront with my js/css files or using a common cdn for them. I'm not going to argue with you, my question makes sense and is logical for StackOverflow.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide the details of your application, run the experiment, provide the metrics from the experiment, and then ask a concrete, closed-ended questions. My guess is, after you run the experiment you will have the information you need.

Comment: we can see the load time difference our self via browser's developer tools > network, can't we? maxcdn is good, but how can we know about that "your own cdn"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a CDN was one of the biggest task in the olden days not anymore.

In addition to using cloudfront, you can checkout webpack where it can bundle all your javascript, minify and have that as a single file. It will also reduce the number of requests it need to make to load your page.

I addition to that enabling compression will make the file compressed automatically with CloudFront.

Apart from all these features, you can enable Authentication, Authorization and Blacklist IP, Countries and a lot more.

Have it in front of CloudFront will make your application safer, faster and scales as you needed.

Hope it helps.